# How to Connect to Local SQL Server From Linux Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to connect to my local instance of SQL Server using a linux Docker container running on my Windows machine. I can connect successfully using `Data Source=localhost` when running under Windows. I've [discovered](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23503) that `localhost` is not supported in a connection string on linux, so here is what I've also tried and failed with:

- `Data Source=localhost`
- `Data Source=localhost,1433`
- `Data Source=127.0.0.1`
- `Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433`
- `Data Source=127.0.0.11`
- `Data Source=127.0.0.11,1433`
- `Data Source=172.23.0.1`  - My local IP Address
- `Data Source=172.23.0.1,1433`

My local SQL Server instance does not allow remote connections. I suspect this is why I cannot connect. Do I need to allow remote connections to get this to work? Can I get this working without doing so?

Also, if I have to provide an IP address, is there a way to work out what that address should be programmatically?

Comment: are running sql server on docker container on windows   machine or is it like you want to connect to local instance of sql server running on windows from a docker container running on windows

Comment: I am running SQL Server on my Windows machine and want to connect to it from a Docker container.

Comment: I think you have figured out it `My local SQL Server instance does not allow remote connections. I suspect this is why I cannot connect. Do I need to allow remote connections to get this to work?`

Comment: IF you are on same host,then no need of enabling remote connections ,other wise you will need to enable,try enabling remote connections and check if it resolves the issue

Comment: Did you try running your container with `--net=host` option?

Comment: @TarunLalwani That is a very good idea. I'm using Docker support for Visual Studio, so I've raised this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/40

Comment: A very detailed answer has been written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/3025545

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Data Source=host.docker.internal` as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).