# How do you connect to a local SQL Server DB from within a docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836546/how-to-connect-to-local-sql-server-from-linux-docker-container), but no one has answered it (also asked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/40) without any answers). I'd like to try to get it answered.

I have a Linux Docker Image containing a console app that connects to a local DB instance. DB is on my local PC and not in the docker image

Local server Name : RIXS\RSERVER

Connection String :       `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=RIXS\RSERVER;Database=MyTable1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");`

I've tried
[Adding the docker image to my SQL Servername](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-contact-sql-server-running-in-a-windows-container-from-another-container/25274)

1. dac7889b09b0\RIXS\RSERVER
2. dac7889b09b0\RSERVER

But I'm obviously doing something wrong. Any idea?

Comment: A very detailed answer has been written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/3025545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the container with network mode as **host**.

```
docker run --network=host ...
```

The host mode will make the container share the network interfaces of the host. Thus an address of localhost or 127.0.0.1 inside the container will refer to the host machine.